# Adding a JTextField into a JOptionPane: ShowOptionDialog

Tags: java, dialog, jtextfield, joptionpane

I was wondering if it is possible to add a JTextField to a ShowOptionDialog box.

```
     int optionChosen = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(finishPayInput,     
     dialogPanel, "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,      
     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);
```

When I run the program, the dialog box shows, but the JTextField doesn't display.

Comment: Where is a `JTextField`?

Comment: @Jens Right at the front: finishPayInput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add a textfield to the `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` first Parameter is the parent component not a child component.

See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)):

> public static int showOptionDialog(Component parentComponent,
>                      Object message,
>                      String title,
>                      int optionType,
>                      int messageType,
>                      Icon icon,
>                      Object[] options,
>                      Object initialValue)
>                               throws HeadlessException
>
> Brings up a dialog with a specified icon, where the initial choice is
>   determined by the initialValue parameter and the number of choices is
>   determined by the optionType parameter.  If optionType is
>   YES_NO_OPTION, or YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION and the options parameter is
>   null, then the options are supplied by the look and feel.
>
> The messageType parameter is primarily used to supply a default icon
>   from the look and feel. Parameters:parentComponent - determines the
>   Frame in which the dialog is displayed; if null, or if the
>   parentComponent has no Frame, a default Frame is usedmessage - the
>   Object to displaytitle - the title string for the dialogoptionType -
>   an integer designating the options available on the dialog:
>   DEFAULT_OPTION, YES_NO_OPTION, YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, or
>   OK_CANCEL_OPTIONmessageType - an integer designating the kind of
>   message this is, primarily used to determine the icon from the
>   pluggable Look and Feel: ERROR_MESSAGE, INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
>   WARNING_MESSAGE, QUESTION_MESSAGE, or PLAIN_MESSAGEicon - the icon to
>   display in the dialogoptions - an array of objects indicating the
>   possible choices the user can make; if the objects are components,
>   they are rendered properly; non-String objects are rendered using
>   their toString methods; if this parameter is null, the options are
>   determined by the Look and FeelinitialValue - the object that
>   represents the default selection for the dialog; only meaningful if
>   options is used; can be nullReturns:an integer indicating the option
>   chosen by the user, or CLOSED_OPTION if the user closed the
>   dialogThrows:HeadlessException - if GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless
>   returns trueSee Also:GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course.
Easiest solution:

```
JTextField txt = new JTextField();
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, finishPayInput, "The Title", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
```

However, if you only want to display `JTextField` (to obtain users input), best idea would be to use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert value: ", "The title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```